# Excel string to criteria

Tags: excel

I have an Excel formula like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A11;{"1010";"1020"};B2:B11))
```

Now I need to make the formula more dynamic. Instead of changing the formula itself, I should be able to change some cell (linked in the formula). This change will be reflected in the formula.
Ex:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A11;D2;B2:B11))
```

Cell **D2** should return something similar to **{"1010";"1020"}** in the first formula.
I tried this and it works only if in the column **D** I have one value (ex: 1020), but if there are two values (ex: 1010;1020) it returns 0.

This is how my table looks like:

[image]

As you can see, it shows 0 for the cell where D2 has two values; but it works when there is only one value. **All the rows in column D will be like cell D2, with 2 or more values, this is why it has to be dynamic using a list in the formula.**

How can this be achieved in Excel? How can I make a list from the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple cells would be easier! If the formula cell is one to the right of the criteria cell, you can define a named formula (Using Name Manager) called, say, GetList, which refers to this formula:

=EVALUATE("{"&INDIRECT("RC[-1]";0)&"}")

Then your formula becomes:

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A11;GetList;B2:B11))

Comment: Thanks, but I must use a single cell.

Comment: Most of my answer assumed that!

Comment: I tried with the first formula, but I think it looks on the first column (column A). How can I make it look on column D?

Comment: It looks at the column one to the left of the formula cell for the criteria. If you need to adjust that, change the -1 in the INDIRECT function.