# Excel SUMIF based on array using text string

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a way to substitute the cell address containing a text string as the array criteria in the following formula?

=SUM(SUMIF(A5:A10,{1,22,3},E5:E10))

So instead of {1,22,3}, "1, 22, 3" is entered in cell A2 the formula becomes
=SUM(SUMIF(A5:A10,A2,E5:E10))

I have tried but get 0 as a result (refer C16)

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
1   Tree                            
2   {1,22,3}                1           
3                   22          
4   Tree    Profit          3           
5   1   105                     
6   2   96                      
7   1   105                     
8   1   75                      
9   2   76.8                        
10  1   45                      
11                              
12          330 =SUM(SUMIF(A5:A10,{1,22,3},B5:B10))             
13                              
14          330 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A5:A10,E2:E3,B5:B10))             
15                              
16          0   =SUM(SUMIF(A5:A10,A2,B5:B10))               
17              NB: Custom Format "{"@"}" on Cell A2 I enter 1,22,3 so it displays {1,22,3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some further searching (see [Excel string to criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764678/excel-string-to-criteria?rq=1)) and trial and error I have come up with the following solution.

Using Name Manager I created UDF called GetList which Refers to:

=EVALUATE(Sheet1!$A$3) NB: Cell A3 has this formula in it =TEXT(A2,"{@}")

I then used the following formula:

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($A$5:$A$12,GetList,$B$5:$B$12))

which gives the desired result of 321 as per the other two formulas (see D12 below).

If anyone can suggest a better solution then feel free to do so.

Thanks to Dennis to my original post regarding table

```
        A        B          C        D          E
    1   Tree                
    2   1,22,3                       1
    3  {1,22,3} =TEXT(A2,"{@}")      22
    4   Tree    Profit               3
    5   11      105         
    6   22      96          
    7   1       105         
    8   3       75          
    9   2       76.8            
    10  1       45          
    11                  
    12                              321 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($A$5:$A$12,GetList,$B$5:$B$12))   
    13                  
    14                              321 =SUM(SUMIF(A5:A10,{1,22,3},B5:B10)) 
    15                  
    16                              321 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A5:A10,E2:E3,B5:B10)) 
    17                  
    18                              0   =SUM(SUMIF(A5:A10,A2,B5:B10))   
    19                      NB: Custom Format "{"@"}" on Cell A2 I enter 1,22,3 so it displays {1,22,3}
```